# how could I convert c++ to python

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {   
  int n;
  int i;  
  int k; 
  cout << "please insert n";

  cin >> n; k=0 ;

  for (i = n; i > 1; i--) {
    cout << "/n "<< k << "+" << i << "=" << i + k++;
  }

  return 0;     
}
```

I'm trying to reproduce the above code in python, but I'm not sure what I'm getting wrong. I'm not sure how to start at a number, then decrement until the condition is met. Here's what I have so far:

```
k=0
n=4
for i in range(n)
 if i > 1 :
  i-=1
  k+=1
print(i+k++)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `range(n)` should be `range(n, 1, -1)` also there is no such operator in Python `k++` you'd need an extra step `k += 1`

Comment: but this don't fix the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n = int(input("please insert n : "))
k = 0
for i in range(n,1,-1):
    print('\n',k,'+',i,'=',i+k)
    k=k+1
```

`range` solves half of the problem itself. Rest of the thing is just formatting and inputting the number.

`range(n,1,-1)` means the range starts from `n` and ends in `1` and there is a step of `-1` in between them.

`n, n+(-1), n+(-2),...,1`.

---

Your C++ program generates wrong output:-

`/n 1+4=4/n 2+3=4/n 3+2=4`

#### Correct code:

```
for(i=n,k=0; i > 1 ; i--,k++){
   cout << "\n "<< k << "+" << i << "=" << i + k;
}
```

You meant `\n` (newline) in `C++` not `/n`.

Comment: range(n,1,-1) what does that mean?

Comment: @moustafasoama from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range): `range(start, stop[, step])`

Comment: @coderredoc  thank's a lot

Answer (score 2):

You need a for loop that decrements.

```
# range(4,1,-1) would give a list of [4,3,2]
# for loop iterates through each number.
k = 0
n = 4
# This iterates from n = 4 to 1
# decrementing one step at a time, needn't specifically handle i in your loop body. 
# So i would get values of 4,3,2
for i in range(n,1,-1):
    print(k,i)
    # no ++ operator in python.
    k+=1
```